# C++ returing a reference to a value in vector

Tags: c++, reference, c++17, stdvector, unordered-map

Given the following program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_map>

#ifdef WITHPAIR
auto get_state() {
    std::pair<std::vector<unsigned>, std::unordered_map<unsigned, unsigned&>> st;

    auto& v = st.first;
    auto& index = st.second;

    v.assign({1u,2u,3u,4u});

    index.insert({0u, v[0]});
    index.insert({1u, v[1]});
    index.insert({2u, v[2]});
    index.insert({3u, v[3]});

    return st;
}

#else

std::pair<std::vector<unsigned>, std::unordered_map<unsigned, unsigned&>> get_state() {
    std::vector v{1u,2u,3u,4u};
    std::unordered_map<unsigned, unsigned&> index{
            {0u, v[0]},
            {1u, v[1]},
            {2u, v[2]},
            {3u, v[3]}
    };

    return {v, index};
}
#endif

auto main() -> int {
    auto [v, index] = get_state();
//    auto [v, index] = std::move(get_state());
    std::cout << v[0] << " " << index.at(0) << std::endl;
    v[0] = 5;
    std::cout << v[0] << " " << index.at(0) << std::endl;
    std::cout << v[1] << " " << index.at(1) << std::endl;
    v[2] = 17;
    std::cout << v[2] << " " << index.at(2) << std::endl;
    std::cout << v[3] << " " << index.at(3) << std::endl; 

    return 0;
}
```

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f9e528074ae78c03

Compile without `-DWITHPAIR` to see behaviour of second function

---

There are two versions of the function `get_state`.

Only the first function seems to have the right behaviour and actually makes that data usable when returned from the function (as you can see from the linked program); the second function does not behave this way and values in the unordered_map is different from what is in the vector.

My question is two:

- Is the behaviour of the first function correct? Is it undefined behaviour or not?
- Why does the second one change the vector?

Comment: Because second one has UB, first one not

Comment: @Slava please state that as an answer. What is the UB of the second one?

Comment: In second one `v` is not moved, but copied so all references are invalidated. If you move `v` explicitly it should fix it.

Comment: @Slava That fixed it. Why in the case of the first one does the copy work?

Comment: Because there is no copy in the first one due to RVO

Comment: Actually I think I see what you meant by copying. So I copied `v` when I put it in the returned pair? But doesn't this mean the map was copied too?

Comment: Yes it is copied to, you should move it as well, but that for efficiency and consistency, but not moving `v` brings UB due to invalidated references in the map.

Comment: @Slava thanks. If you want to give this as an answer, I will accept otherwise I will just leave it here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first function seems to work due to [NRVO](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision):

> In a return statement, when the operand is the name of a non-volatile object with automatic storage duration, which isn't a function parameter or a catch clause parameter, and which is of the same class type (ignoring cv-qualification) as the function return type. This variant of copy elision is known as NRVO, "named return value optimization".

if it happens there is no copy performed and references in the map are still valid, but since NRVO is an optimization and not guaranteed you are just lucky this works.

In the second function you create temporary object of type `std::pair<std::vector<unsigned>, std::unordered_map<unsigned, unsigned&>>` and you use lvalues `v` and `index` to initialize it, so copy constructors are invoked for both of them and all references become invalid when original `v` is destroyed. Fix could be to call `std::move` explicitly:

```
return {std::move(v), index};
```

and as standard guarantees that references remain valid and would point to elements in the new vector so there should be no UB anymore. `index` should be moved as well for efficiency and consistency as well, but I left it as it is not related to the question.

This is pretty dangerous way of programming and I would consider different data types (probably index in the vector instead of reference).

Comment: Thanks for the advice at the end. I quickly realized this after I tried to make a copy of the pair

Comment: @smac89 np, it is usually not a good idea to have references in a container but references to a vector elements are even worse.

Comment: This is NRVO, and isn't guaranteed.